# How to make a model in loopback 4 to have unique values in its schema?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, loopbackjs

I am trying to find a way to have the same funtionality that happens when I put 
unique:true in express schema. How do I accomplish this in loopback 4. I tried putting unique true in the property decorator but it did not work.

```
@property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    required: false,
    unique: true,
  })
  id: string;
```

This doesnt work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@property` decorator in LB4 borrows the same properties as in LB3. Assuming that I have understood your requirements, you can make use of the `index` property to enforce the uniqueness of a field across the collection. 
For a field like 'id', the property decorator would take the following arguments:

```
@property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    required: false,
    index: {
        unique: true
    }
  })
  id: string;
```

Moreover, if you are using the 'id' generated by MongoDB, you do not need to enforce uniqueness explicitly but the above should work for other fields like email, username etc.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. But where did you read about this info? Like where was the implemetation? Thx again

Comment: Loopback 4 documentation is modest but for most use-cases, you will find what you are looking for if you look close enough. For [property decorator](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html#property-decorator), this is what they have which references to [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#properties) in LB3 documentation. Scroll down and you will get your answer. Just like you I am also getting my feet wet with LB4 :)

Comment: Doesn't work on LB4 for mongodb. I'm trying to make email unique without success

Comment: one need to migrate his loopback v4 project in order fort this to take effect use `npm run migrate`