# How do I query a particular field in loopback 4 through the repository?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, v4l2loopback

I want to enforce uniqueness so I would like to see if there are any other emails and usernames that are similar to the one posted to this route. How do I do that through the repository, it keeps on asking about a filter which I see but cannot get my head around it.

```
@post('/users', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: {'x-ts-type': User}}},
      },
    },
  })
  async create(@requestBody() user: User): Promise<User> {
    //check : User= await this.userRepository.create(user);
    //@param.query.object('filter', getFilterSchemaFor(User)) filter?: Filter;
    // var check:any=await this.userRepository.find(filter);
    //filter: Filter;
    var check: User = await this.userRepository.find({email:user.email});
    var isNotPresent: boolean = true;
    // check.forEach(function(val){

    // });
    // if(isNotPresent)
    return await this.userRepository.create(user);
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Filter` object has the following properties that can be used to define a query and it's response:

1. `where`: Used to define a query. In your case, you would like to find existing users with the same email and username as provided in the request body.
2. `fields`: To specify fields that you would like to include or exclude in the response of your query. Every object in the array returned by `find()` will have only those fields which are set to `true` in the `fields` object.
3. `offset`, `skip`, `limit` and `order`: Used for pagination.

So, in your case, assuming a 'user' has an 'email' and an 'username', the filter object would look like the following:

```
const filter: Filter = {
    where: {
        'email': user.email,
        'username': user.username
    },
    fields: {
        email: true,
        username: true
    },
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10,
    skip: 0,
    order: [],
};
```

And your call to the repository method would look like the following:

```
var check: User = await this.userRepository.find(filter);
```

My first SO answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Believe me when I say you saved me from breaking my head. Also congrats on your first answer.

Comment: Could you try this question as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993621/how-to-make-a-model-in-loopback-4-to-have-unique-values-in-its-schema
I came up with a hack but hopefully there is a better way

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! As for your other question, are you trying to ensure that every 'id' is unique across the entire collection? Also, I am not aware of 'express-schema'  but since you have tagged the question with 'mongodb' I am assuming you are referring to 'mongoose schema'. Let me know.

Comment: I mean the when we make express applications we in the model file make it for it to be unique like username should be unique, email should be unique. That sort of thing

Comment: I have taken a stab at your question. Hope it helps.